# Can't get any video preview with AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, video, ios5, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I set up my `AVCaptureSession`like so:

```
AVCaptureSession *newSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
AVCaptureDevice *camera = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

NSError *error = nil;

AVCaptureDeviceInput *newInput = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] initWithDevice:camera error:&error];


if(error) {
    NSLog([error localizedDescription]);

}

AVCaptureMovieFileOutput *newOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];


if([newSession canAddInput:newInput])
    [newSession addInput:newInput];
if ([newSession canAddOutput:newOutput])
    [newSession addOutput:newOutput];

[self setSession:newSession];
[self setInput:newInput];
[self setOutput:newOutput];
```

And then I added a preview layer to my view:

```
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *layer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:[recorder session]];

[layer setBounds:[recordingView bounds]];
[layer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];

[[recordingView layer] insertSublayer:layer above:[recordingView layer]];
```

But I wont get any preview.

I'm on IOS 5 with an iPod Touch 4th Gen.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, how is your `recordingView` defined?
Second,

```
[[recordingView layer] insertSublayer:layer above:[recordingView layer]];
```

makes no sense. (you are trying to add a layer above  the own layer inside the own layer ->duh?)
Try `[recordingView.layer addSublayer:layer];` instead.

Your posted project in the comments uses zeroing weak pointers. mark your properties strong instead and everything works.

Comment: `recordingView` is just an `UIView` inside my `MainViewController`.

Changed that, but didnt fix it...

Comment: You also should start your session after the init. `[newSession startRunning];`

Comment: Well I did, just forgot to copy it.
I think the problem might be somewhere else...

Here's the whole project (if thats allowed...): http://www21.zippyshare.com/v/26365272/file.html

Its not much, just 5 classes or so.

Comment: Stop using weak properties and use strong instead. Only delegates and outlets should be weak. Your code works for me if i change all your properties (except your outlets) to strong.

Comment: Why do I have to use strong properties there?

Comment: Imho the best resource for that is the wwdc 2011 session video "Introducing Automatic Reference Counting". You can find it on the developer portal https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/
Or just google for ARC (automatic reference counting).

Comment: Thanks, gonna check that out :)